# System of equations word problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One number is greater by 6 than twice another number, but 3 times the smaller number exceeds the greater by 1. Find the numbers.

I got

$$x = 2y + 6$$

$$3y = x + 1$$

$$3y = 2y + 6 + 1$$

$$y = 7$$

$$x = 2(7) + 6$$

Comment: What you wrote literally makes no sense. You have simply translated the expressions in the sentence and strung them all together with addition. Why do you think this captures the information you were given? "One number is greater by 6 than twice another number" is a single sentence. If $x$ is the first number and $y$ is the second number, this is saying $x$ is 6 greater than twice $y$. In other words, $x=6+2y$. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is the larger number, and $y$ is the smaller number, I get the following two equations:
$$x = 2y+6,$$
$$3y=x+1.$$

Comment: Will you help me solve it?

Comment: @W.Zlacki yes, I will. I suggest taking the expression for $x$ in the first equation and plug it into the second equation. So take $2y+6$ and plug it into $3y=x+1$ instead of $x$. What do you get?

Comment: $$3y = 2y + 6 + 1$$

Comment: @W.Zlacki that's right. Can you simplify that a bit? Start with adding the $6$ and the $1$ to get $3y = 2y+7$. Then I suggest subtracting $2y$ from both sides of the equation. What do you get?

Comment: $$y = 7$$ is what you get.

Comment: @W.Zlacki yeah. So you can plug this value for $y$ into the first equation $x=2y+6$ to get $x$. It looks like you've already solved it though.

Answer (score 1):

> One number is greater by 6 than twice another number

$$x - 2y = 6$$

> $3$ times the smaller number exceeds the greater by $1$. Find the numbers.

we conclude from the above equation, that $x > y$ since the right-hand-side is positive. That is the smaller number is $y$

$$3y-x=1$$

Now we have 2 equations in 2 variables.

$$3y - x = 1$$
$$x - 2y = 6$$

The system can be written as:

$$-x + 3y = 1$$
$$x - 2y = 6$$

It is easy to get rid of $x$ by adding the $2$ equations:

$$x-x+3y-2y=1+6$$

That is:

$$y=7$$

You can plug this in any of the original $2$ equations to get $x$:

$$x - 2*7=6$$

$$x=6+14=20$$

At this point it is good to test the solution with the original statements to make sure all conditions are satisfied.